# Resume failed download using retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

While downloading large files with Retrofit our downloads often fail due to poor mobile connection.

Is there any way to resume a failed download offered by retrofit?

**Current Idea:**

With the `@Streaming` annotation downloaded content should be directly downloaded to a file. If the download fails we could check the partly downloaded file for its length and then request the missing data via `Content-Range` http parameter.

Has anybody done this before? Is this possible?

Comment: You can use Content-Range for the entire file. Download it in x size chunks until you have the entire file. If a chunk fails, just retry it until it succeeds and move on to the next one.

Comment: Had the same idea. Have you done it? Do you have a code example?